# How to match pattern in line and insert it after another pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with 2 lines

```
1, output /test here    
2, output /test here
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
1, output /test 1 here    
2, output /test 2 here
```

so that the string before the `,` is copied behind the `/test` string.

How can I do this with `awk` or `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really only talks about "the string before the first comma on the line" and "the string `/test`" after which the string that matches the first pattern should be duplicated (with a delimiting space).

```bsh
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),.*\/test/& \1/' file
```

This replaces the substring matching the whole expression with itself, followed by a space and the substring matching before the first comma. It makes no further assumptions about the contents of the line.

The output, given the data in the question:

```
1, output /test 1 here
2, output /test 2 here
```

Would you want to replace the `/test` text with the substring from the start of the line (this is hinted at [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662919/how-to-match-pattern-in-line-and-insert-it-after-another-pattern/662926#comment1247610_662920)):

```bsh
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*\),.*\)\/test/\1\2/' file
```

This replaces the same bit of the line as with the first `sed` command, but instead of just appending the bit from the start of the line, this does not include the `/test` string at the end.  The replacement reuses the space character in front of `/test`, so no new space needs to be inserted.

The output from this with the same input data:

```
1, output 1 here
2, output 2 here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Capturing Groups and Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) ex.

```
sed 's:\([^,]*\), output /test:& \1:' file
```

Since you also tagged your question `awk`, you could also do something like

```
awk -F, 'match($0,/\/test/) {print substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) $1, substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}' file
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace the test text also so it become 1, output /1 here    
2, output /2 here

Comment: @TeonaKharchilava it's very easy with the awk version - just replace `RSTART+RLENGTH` with `RSTART` in the first `substr`. For the sed version, you'd need to forgo `&` in favor of explicit capture groups ex. `s:\([^,]*\)\(, output \)/test:\1\2\1:`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]*),\s([a-z].*\s.[a-z]*)\s([a-z].*)/\1 \2 \1 \3/'
```

`sed` solution simply groups the matches so they can be rearranged when substituting retaining original values.

```
awk -F"[, ]" '{sub($4, $4" "$1)}1'
```

This `awk` solution as above will substitute the value of column 4 with the original value of column 4 `/test` and append the value of column 1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` solution can help:

```
awk '/\/test/ {$3=$3 " " $1;sub(/,$/,"",$3)} 1' file
1, output /test 1 here
2, output /test 2 here
```